# Allow HTML in product titles - Magento

Tags: magento

so here is the scenerio.

I want to display bare html in the product titles. But magento strips any html in the product title as you can see here (https://swadeshiherbal.com/khomba-baby-cologne-herbal-100ml-6.html) .

Please help me to find the template file that magento uses to display these titles so that I can remove any html escaping functions from there.

I tried to find the function but couldn't find it. however the below file contained a function call like so

```
public_html/app/code/Magiccart/Alothemes/Controller/Product/View.php

$pageMainTitle->setPageTitle($product->getName());
```

but it doesn't have any escaping functions

pleaese help

Comment: solved it myself by using template hints. Thanks for viewing

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is pondering upon a question such as this I shall hav eno hesitation in recommending template hints.

Store Configuration -> Developer